# Invoke ToList() method using reflection at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a generic as follows.

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{...}
```

I simply want to invoke ToList() method on that object at runtime using reflection.

Can someone please help.

I have come so only far.

```
MethodInfo toListMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList");
var constructedToList = toListMethod.MakeGenericMethod(TypeObjectOfT);
constructedToList.Invoke(paginatedListObject, null);
```

**I get exception** at the last line with message, **Parameter count mismatch**. I feel that the first two steps are ok, as I have checked the `toListMethod.ToString()` and `constructedToList.ToString()`. And they have given me the following output, which I feel is correct.

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TSource] ToList[TSource](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TSource])
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AvbhHis.BL.Entities.PatientCategory] ToList[PatientCategory](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[AvbhHis.BL.Entities.PatientCategory])
```

**Questions:** 
1. Am I right so far?

2. What should be the parameter to `MakeGenericMethod()` method. In my case it is the Type of intance of the object of Type T at runtime.
3. There seems to be some problem with the Invoke method call. Is passing null correct as second parameter? The first parameter should be an object of the type PaginatedList right?

My energy is out, so kindly help.

Comment: @Hani, you a bit confuse: `Enumerable` is a class that contains extension methods for `IEnumerable<T>`. Also [msdn say that _Enumerable **does** have ToList()_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Mixing generics and reflection is generally a code smell - is there not a way to call `ToList` generically in your situation?

Comment: @Grundy You are confused - OP _is_ calling `ToList` on `Enumerable` via reflection.

Comment: @DStanley, yep :-) possibly i not quite understand previous comment Hani :-)

Comment: the point is that ToList is an extension method not, a method on IEnumerable. Its a static method on an extension class that takes an IENumerable as its first paramter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The first parameter [to `Invoke`] should be an object of the type PaginatedList right?

`ToList` is a static method on `Enumerable` that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` as it's only parameter:

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source
)
```

[`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx) takes the *instance* as the first parameter and the *method parameters* after that.  For a static method you use `null` for the "instance" parameter.

So the proper syntax would be

```
object o = constructedToList.Invoke(null, new object[] {paginatedListObject});
```

`o` will then be an object of type `List<T>` (but you don't know kniw what `T` is at compile time, so you can't cast it).

Comment: I get this exception now during the invocation. "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(object, object[])' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: @DumbDev Try it now - I forgot that `Invoke` doesn't use `params` so the second parameter must be passed as an array.

Comment: Thank you Stanley. Its working now perfectly.  Since I have to select only one, I shall select yours without much judgement.

Answer (score 2):

List<T> has a constructor that takes an IEnumerable<T> (Which gets called in ToList) so you can simplyfy this task by writing the following:

```
    var resul = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(TypeObjectOfT), paginatedListObject);
```

Comment: This is also a cute answer.

Comment: Make generic type takes an array as the first argument. .MakeGenericType(new Type[] { TypeObjectOfT })

Comment: @BojidarStanchev correct but it has the params keyword, so you dont need to delcare an array.